# TensorFlow 2.13.0 cannot use GPU

Tags: tensorflow

TensorFlow 2.13.0 GPU, what versions of cuda and cudnn are required?

```
$ python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.version.GIT_VERSION, tf.version.VERSION)"

v2.13.0-rc2-7-g1cb1a030a62 2.13.0
```

Ubuntu22.04 system

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above is to install cuda and cudnn versions.
But the GPU is not recognized.

[image]

[image]

So, what versions of cuda and cudnn are needed？

Answer (score 2):

CUDA `11.8` and cuDNN `8.6` seem to be the correct versions for TensorFlow `2.13`.

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu